How to visualize the vector field and deformation of grid when applying grid_sample
I am trying to visualize the deformation of a grid when applying grid_sample. For example, my source image is a simple square image, along a displacement field that deform the square image to a circle image. I want to visualize the deformation of the grid with vector field of how each pixel is moved. I can do that when create an grid image and apply grid_sample to the grid image. However, I am not sure how to replicate that and show the vector field using LineCollection and quiver with matplotlib. Could you help me with that? Thanks!

import numpy as np
import cv2
import torch

from torch.nn.functional import grid_sample

class SimpleReg(torch.nn.Module):
    """
    a simple cnn model that take coordinates map as input and output the registration result
    such that when apply the grid_sample function, the input image will be transformed to the target image
    input: nx 2 x h x w
    output: nx 2 x h x w
    """

    def __init__(self):
        super(SimpleReg, self).__init__()
        self.conv = torch.nn.Sequential(
            torch.nn.Conv2d(2, 16, 3, 1, 1),
            torch.nn.ReLU(),
            torch.nn.Conv2d(16, 32, 3, 1, 1),

            torch.nn.ReLU(),
            torch.nn.Conv2d(32, 64, 3, 1, 1),
            torch.nn.ReLU(),
            torch.nn.Conv2d(64, 2, 3, 1, 1),
        )

    def forward(self, x):
        return self.conv(x)

def gen_square(image_size: int, fraction: float) -> np.ndarray:
    image = np.zeros((image_size, image_size), dtype=np.float32)
    square_size = int(image_size * fraction)

    start = (image_size - square_size) // 2
    end = start + square_size
    image[start:end, start:end] = 1.0
    return image


def gen_circle(image_size: int, fraction: float) -> np.ndarray:
    image = np.zeros((image_size, image_size), dtype=np.float32)
    circle_size = int(image_size * fraction)
    cv2.circle(image, (image_size // 2, image_size // 2), circle_size // 2, 1.0, -1)
    return image

def gen_grid_image(size, n_lines=50, line_width=0.1):
    image = np.zeros((size, size), dtype=np.float32)

    # Generate horizontal lines
    for i in range(n_lines):
        y = int(size / (n_lines + 1) * (i + 1))
        image[y, :] = 1.0

    # Generate vertical lines
    for i in range(n_lines):
        x = int(size / (n_lines + 1) * (i + 1))
        image[:, x] = 1.0

    return image

def visualize_deformation_field_with_lines(phi, grid_size=25, vector_scale=1):
    """
    Visualize the deformation field by plotting deformed grid lines and overlaying the deformation vector field.
    """

    pass

# Create the images
size = 256
fraction = 0.7

input_shape = gen_square(size, fraction)
target_shape = gen_circle(size, fraction)
grid_image = gen_grid_image(size, 50)

# Convert the images to tensors

input_tensor = torch.tensor(input_shape).unsqueeze(0).unsqueeze(0)
target_tensor = torch.tensor(target_shape).unsqueeze(0).unsqueeze(0)
grid_tensor = torch.tensor(grid_image).unsqueeze(0).unsqueeze(0)

# Get domain of the input and target coordinates
input_coords = np.indices((size, size)).astype(np.float32)
input_coords = input_coords / (size * 0.5) - 1.0
input_coords = torch.tensor(input_coords).unsqueeze(0)


# Create the model
model = SimpleReg()

# Define the loss function and optimizer
criterion = torch.nn.MSELoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.001)

# convert everything to cuda
model = model.cuda()
input_tensor = input_tensor.cuda()
target_tensor = target_tensor.cuda()
input_coords = input_coords.cuda()
grid_tensor = grid_tensor.cuda()

# Train the model
for epoch in range(1000):
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    outputs_grid = model(input_coords)
    outputs_grid = input_coords.detach() + outputs_grid
    # normalize the outputs to [-1, 1]
    outputs_grid = torch.clamp(outputs_grid, -1, 1)
    outputs = grid_sample(input_tensor, outputs_grid.permute(0, 2, 3, 1), mode='bilinear', padding_mode='zeros')
    vis_grid_tensor = grid_sample(grid_tensor, outputs_grid.permute(0, 2, 3, 1), mode='bilinear', padding_mode='zeros')
    loss = criterion(outputs, target_tensor)
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()



    if epoch % 10 == 0:
        print(f"Epoch {epoch}: Loss: {loss.item()}")

        vis = np.concatenate([input_shape,
                              outputs.squeeze().detach().cpu().numpy(),
                              target_shape,
                                vis_grid_tensor.squeeze().detach().cpu().numpy()
                              ], axis=1)

        cv2.imshow("Visualization", vis)
        cv2.waitKey(0)



